# Debugging logs for a Lightning app which implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess"

Tags: lightning-apps, debugging

Using the link below,

> https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_apps_in_communities.htm

by adding the ltng:allowGuestAccess interface to my Lightning app, I am making it available to public users. So my app is available as a stand-alone Lightning app at the following URL: `https://yourCommunityDomain/communityURL/namespace/appName.app.`

But the problem is I am not able to debug Apex logs. I tried this method of setting the cookie, but its not working

```
document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=.force.com";
```

Can anybody guide me? Things are working fine from developer console.

Comment: Along with this you also need to enable debug logs for site guest user

Comment: I have done that too.